# Can I divide entire equations by each other when trying to solve a system of non-linear equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have the following equations:

---

1. $\frac{F}{(W-\phi)t}=\sigma_{_L}$
2. $\frac{F}{(W^2-\phi^2)t}=\tau_{_L}$
3. $\frac{F}{\phi t}=\sigma_{_L}$
4. $\frac{F}{\phi^2\pi/4}=\tau_{_P}$

---

I then solve for F

---

1. $F=(W-\phi)t\sigma_{_L}$
2. $F=(W^2-\phi^2)t\tau_{_L}$
3. $F=\phi t\sigma_{_L}$
4. $F=\phi^2\frac{\pi}{4}\tau_{_P}$

---

Since they are all in terms of F, I can divide any of these equations by another and I should get 1.

---

1./2. $\frac{(W-\phi)t\sigma_{_L}}{(W^2-\phi^2)t\tau_{_L}}=1$

3./4. $\frac{\phi t\sigma_{_L}}{\phi^2\frac{\pi}{4}\tau_{_P}}=1$

---

Now I can set them equal to each other and solve for different variables.

---

1./2. = 3./4. $\frac{(W-\phi)t\sigma_{_L}}{(W^2-\phi^2)t\tau_{_L}}=\frac{\phi t\sigma_{_L}}{\phi^2\frac{\pi}{4}\tau_{_P}}$

---

This seems like a logical approach, but I am not sure if there is a flaw in my logic since I could end up with a very different equation (after simplification) if I instead did 1./4. = 2./3. or any permutation thereof.

Is my approach incorrect? Is there a better way to do this (besides doing substitution)?

Comment: If you have $a=b$ and $c=d$ and you know that $c\not=0$, then you have $a/c=b/d$. Here, you just do that where $a$ and $c$ are $F$. So your logic is ok, unless $F=0$.

Comment: Another thing is that $(1) a = b$ and $(2) c = d$ imply (assuming $c\not=0$) $(3) a/c=b/d$ but to have an equivalent system, you need to keep either ($(1)$ and $(3)$) or ($(2)$ and $(3)$). All solutions to $(1)$ and $(2)$ will satisfy $(3)$ but some solutions of $(3)$ may satisfy neither $(1)$ nor $(2)$.

Comment: @xavierm02 I'm not sure what you mean by only keeping (1 and 3) or (2 and 3). 3 is the direct result of 1 and 2 so if I kept 3, wouldn't I automatically have (for lack of a better word) the "essence" of 1 and 2? How can I go about getting a solution that would satisfy all of my equations? I am familiar with solving SLE, and so I'm not sure what the rules that apply here are.

Comment: No. For example, if you have $x=6$ and $y=3$, you can deduce $x/y=2$ but $(x,y)=(2,1)$ is a solution of $x/y=2$ that is neither a solution of $x=6$ nor a solution of $y=3$.

Comment: Excellent example. Could you suggest an approach that would allow me to simultaneously find solutions for all of the equations? Substitution perhaps?

Comment: On a second look at your example. Wouldn't my case be different since I have my equations all in terms of F. I.e. $F = x$ and $F = y$ So $F/F = 1 = x/y$  would be all of the solutions. Where $x = y$.

Comment: In most cases, you won't be able to reduce the number of equation: when you combine two equations to create a third one, you have to keep at least one old one. A method is to find solutions to one of the equations and the search for solutions of the second equation in by plugging in the shape of solutions if the first one.

Comment: $0=x$ and $0=y$ imply $x=y$ that clearly allows new solutions. You're in that case with F instead of 0.